# Scikit-learn external documentation url for pycharm?

Tags: scikit-learn, ide, pycharm, documentation

I see that it's possible to add external documentation in pycharm and you need to set the url for external documentation but I'm unable to find the url for scikit-learn.

I was wondering if anyone know the url pattern for Scikit-learn?

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/{element.qname}.html#{element.qname}
```